# Angular Formarray Load Multiple Value

Tags: javascript, angular

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9x23.png)

I want to loop those values in this html. using form control. please help me on this. having trouble to displaying values on that table. what is the best way to display those array values on table. TIA please see sample image for reference. im using reactive form and form group and form array. angular 14

```js
 this.empform =this._fb.group({
     
      id: [''],
      issuingsitelocation: [''],
      jrnumber: [''],
      employeeid: [''],
      sso: [''],
      name: [''],
      transporttype: [''],
      deliverystage: [''],
      status: [''],
      remedyreq: [''],
      corrected: [''],
      tocancel: [''],
      modified: [''],
      created: [''],
      startdate: [''],
      location: [''],
      city: [''],
      postcode: [''],
      client: [''],
      employementstatus: [''],
      cnxwahstatus: [''],
      packagedescription: [''],
      otherperipherals: [''],
      softwarecheckitemstocheck: [''],
      workerstatus: [''],
      assetstatus: [''],
      positiontitle: [''],
      domiciledsite: [''],
      signoffstatus: [''],
      street: [''],
      phonenumber: [''],
      personalemailaddress: [''],
      transportpoc:[''],
      datebooked:[''],
      trackingnumber: [''],
      scheduledpickupdate: [''],
      drivername: [''],
      driverotherdetails: [''],
      drivercontactnumber: [''],
      driverpicture: [''],
      
      assets:  {
          category: new FormControl('category'),
          name:new FormControl('name'),
          serialNo:new FormControl('serialNo'),
          description:new FormControl('description'),
      }
```

this my html format

```js
        <table formArrayName="assets">
                    <thead>
                      <tr class="header-ad">
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Serial number</th>
                        <th>Description </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <!-- <ng-container [formGroup]="assets"  > -->
                    
                      <tbody *ngFor="let item of assets.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
              
                        <td >

                          <input class="table-cell-ad" [readonly]="true" form matInput type="text" formControlName="id">
                         
                        </td>
                        <td  >
                          <input class="table-cell-ad" [readonly]="true" form matInput type="text" formControlName="category" value="">
                          <label></label>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                          <input class="table-cell-ad" [readonly]="true" form matInput type="text" formControlName="name">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <input class="table-cell-ad" [readonly]="true" form matInput type="text" formControlName="serialNo">
                        </td >
                        <td>
                          <input class="table-cell-ad" [readonly]="true" form matInput type="text" formControlName="description">
                        </td>
                      
                      </tbody>
                
                    <!-- </ng-container> -->
                    

                 </table>
```